# generating Another thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Newbie to Python,  Basically I have a window UI with few buttons, when I push one button, I would like to start processing/parsing files in background while I can still play with the UI, however my UI becomes unresponsive "spinning wheel".

```
class MyUI(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent):

    Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white") 
    self.parent = parent
    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):
 self.validate_button = Button(self,
                text='Validate',
                command=self.validate_files).pack()

def validate_files(self):
    try:
        t = Thread(target=self.process_files(), args=('labala',1))
        t.start
        t.join
    except Exception, errtxt:
        print errtxt

 def process_colls(self):
    items = self.lb.curselection()
    for i in items:
        self.do_parse(self.varDirName, self.lb.get(int(i)))

def main():
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600+300+300")
app = MyUI(root)
root.mainloop() 

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: For me your code is just a blank screen. Are you missing anything?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Python is impossible to interpret without the correct indentation.

Comment: Not just indentation... in `validate_files()` you will just catch your syntax errors :)

Comment: I am not concerned about syntax or identation, I am just trying to figure out why my main thread becomes unresponsive while background thread is processing..By looking at it, can anyone see a problem with starting the thread this way?

Comment: Try providing the fully working code - we have to do extra work for you to reproduce the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: The syntax is not detail in that case: if `join()` in `validate_files()` was executed it could be be issue. If you don't fix the code it is impossible to try to guess where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `self.process_files()` with `self.process_files` where you create the thread:

```
t = Thread(target=self.process_files, args=('labala',1))
```

You should pass a fuction to thread as target and not a result.

Moreover don't use `join()` if you want that the function return while the thread is running.

Comment: self.process_files doesn't fire off the function, self.process_files() does, but still becomes unresponsive. Is this a problem, items = self.lb.curselection(), since its reading the list from the main UI?

Comment: @user1529412 is `self.process_file()` a functor? `target` should be a call back and not a value. If `self.process_file()` return a function I will remove may answer, but you must fix your question because now is impossible understand what happen.

Comment: Hmm I see, I will play with it, any idea why self.process_files isn't triggered?

Comment: Maybe if you replace `t.start` with `t.start()` it could be triggered.

Comment: @user1529412 As I wrote in my previous comment syntax is not a detail.

Comment: I tried, it didn't trigger. I will play with it and let you know how I make out. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I got ot to work by fixing the background function and changed the target like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try starting a thread using `threading.Thread`. This snippet should help you find more answers

```
from threading import Thread

...

_thread = Thread(target=lambda: my_func())
_thread.start()
```

In your example you forgot the parentheses to call methods.

Comment: The function fires off fine, I do get the right results. Your statement and mine are same, I tried them both.